# VS Code Status Bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Wondering if anyone can help and tell me what the icon is in the bottom left hand corner of the vs code window. I don't have it on mine and wondering if I need it.

Circled in red on the image.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: That's the [Git status bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-status-bar-actions). It shows up if the open folder has version control.

Answer (score 3):

It's a Git Status, next to the git branch indicator.
Right-click on the status-bar and ✓check the Source Control option ([After right-clicking on status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2e1n.png)  ) if want it on your status bar,
Uncheck if you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

That's the Git logo which is a version control app. I don't have it either but my guess is that it's a VS extension (not sure which git extension it exactly is). If you don't need version control then it's fine.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get this icon? That is, what extension is it? There are five GitHub extensions.